# Big O notation of a preprocessed static data structure

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o

From what i understand, O(n) will grow linearly in regards to the size of the input data set.

I'm getting confused as I have a querying structure that maps keys to a list of preprocessed values that will not ever change after the structure is initialised.

If i define n as the input, an array of keys.

```
def (arrOfKeys): 
    for key in arrOfKeys: # O(n) Iterating through the input.
        preprocessedList = getPreprocessedListDifferentForEachKey(key) # O(1) this list could have any number of elements.
        for anotherPreprocessedList in preprocessedList: # * <- O(n) or O(1)?
            for element in anotherPreprocessedList: # * <- O(n) or O(1)?
                ...
```

- I'm unsure if this O(1) because it is preprocessed or O(n) as the size of the list is dependent on what the input is?

Does this end up being O(n^3) at the worst case or is it possible to argue O(n)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends, if `preprocessedList` (and its sub-array) is always going to be of a constant length, your 2 inner loops will be of time complexity O(1). If they however are depending on the input argument `arrOfKeys` they will each be of O(n) and thus O(n) * O(n) = O(n^2).

Combined with the first loop you then multiply it with its time complexity which is O(n).

So if the inner loops are each of O(n) it's going to be in total O(n^3)

If the lengths of `preprocessedList` is variable, but not depending on the length of `arrOfKeys` you can define it as `m` and say it's of time complexity O(m). You can then say that the time complexity is O(n*m^2).

It's usually possible to introduce another symbol to describe the time complexity as long as you explain what they are and how they relate to the indata.

Comment: Thanks for this, i missed the point of being able to use more than one symbol to analyse the data!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!